# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@fullcalendar/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, laravel, import, node-modules

I have this error when trying to import fullcalender module.

I already have the dependencies specified in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
"fullcalendar": "^6.1.8",
"jquery": "^3.7.0",
"sweetalert2": "^11.7.12"
}
```

Already have the "npm install" executed

Screenshot here shows the modules are downloaded in the corresponding path

[image]

This is the blade template where it will call the 'availability.js'

```html
<?php $page="calendar";?> @extends('layout.mainlayout') @section('content')

<script type="module" src="{{ url('/admin_system/js/availability.js') }}"></script>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row align-items-center w-100">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
          <h3 class="page-title">Calendar</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add_event">Create Event</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
        <h4 class="card-title">Drag & Drop Event</h4>
        <div id="calendar-events" class="mb-3">
          <div class="calendar-events" data-class="bg-info"><i class="fas fa-circle text-info"></i> My Event One</div>
          <div class="calendar-events" data-class="bg-success"><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> My Event Two</div>
          <div class="calendar-events" data-class="bg-danger"><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> My Event Three</div>
          <div class="calendar-events" data-class="bg-warning"><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> My Event Four</div>

          <div id='draggable-1' data-event='{ "title": "my event", "duration": "02:00" }'>drag me 1</div>
          <div id='draggable-2' data-event='{ "title": "my event", "duration": "02:00" }'>drag me 2</div>
          <div id='draggable-3' data-event='{ "title": "my event", "duration": "02:00" }'>drag me 3</div>


        </div>
        <div class="checkbox  mb-3">
          <input id="drop-remove" type="checkbox">
          <label for="drop-remove">
                        Remove after drop
                    </label>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add_new_event" class="btn mb-3 btn-primary btn-block w-100">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Category
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
        <div class="card bg-white">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="mycalendar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
@component('components.modal-popup') @endcomponent @endsection
```

This is the code snippet of the 'availability.js'

```js
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let draggableEl = document.getElementById('mydraggable');
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('mycalendar');
  let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [interactionPlugin],
    droppable: true
  });
  calendar.render();
  new Draggable(draggableEl);
});
```

I have exhausted all available options in attempting to debug the issue, including seeking assistance from ChatGPT, yet none of the proposed solutions have proven successful ...

Comment: that is pretty obvious error message `from '@fullcalendar/core';
from '@fullcalendar/interaction';` if you expect that to expand, then you need whatever loads the JS file to understand the scoping of your package.json and translate that to a relative path that the module supports

Comment: chatGPT evven says `If you're working in a bundler environment like Webpack or Rollup, or a runtime environment like Node.js, they can resolve module paths starting with a name like @fullcalendar/core but the browser cannot.`